# T-Sql help needed in Sql Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I have created one stored procedure which runs on 5000 users in tbluser table with some filter condition in  database.There are 4 filtering condition(FC1,FC2,FC3,FC4).Filtering condition has some ListBox and dropdown list of department and countries.I want output as given below:

```
ID  Name  StaffNo  department Points
1   KK     111      dep1        2
2   NN     222      dep2        1
3   DD     333      dep3        4
```

I got ID,Name,StaffNo,department in resultset but not points.

points calculation would be based on filtering condition like

if FC1 matched user gained point 1,if both FC1 and FC2 matched user gained 2 point,if both FC1 ,FC2 and FC3 matched user gained 3 point etc.

```
    --in stored procedure i m using dynamic query
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(2000)
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT U.UserID, U.StaffNo,U.FirstName+'' ''+ U.LastName AS EmployeeName,''?'' AS Points FROM tblUser U '
    SET @SQL = @SQL+' WHERE U.Department  in (' + @SqlDepartment + ') '
    ---------------------Update---------------------------------------
IF @SqlLanguage <> ''
    SET @SQL = @SQL+' OR U.UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM Country WHERE LCValues IN ('+ @SqlLanguage +') )'
IF @SqlAreas <> ''
    SET @SQL = @SQL+' OR U.UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM tblAreas WHERE '+@SqlAreas+')'
    ---------------------Update---------------------------------------
    ...other filtering condition
    EXEC (@SQL)
```

all filtering condition are implemented with OR logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried implementing a CASE statement to calculate the "Points"?

```
--in stored procedure i m using dynamic query
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(2000)
SET @SQL = '
    SELECT 
        U.[UserID], 
        U.[StaffNo],
        U.[FirstName]+'' ''+ U.[LastName] AS EmployeeName,
        (
            CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [Country] WHERE /*Your filter comes in here*/) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [tblAreas] WHERE /*Your filter comes in here*/) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [OtherTable1] WHERE /*Your filter comes in here*/) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
            CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [OtherTable2] WHERE /*Your filter comes in here*/) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) AS Points 
    FROM [tblUser] U'
SET @SQL = @SQL+' WHERE U.Department  in (' + @SqlDepartment + ') OR'...
...other filtering condition
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: thanks for giving solution. but in my case FC1,2,3,4 are related to 4 different table not tbluser table

Comment: Are you able to join the tables based on a foreign key, perhaps [UserID]? Could you maybe post an example of what the tables look like so I can give you a better solution?

Comment: I updated my answer with a quick-n-dirty method of achieving what you might be looking for. That's the best I can come up with without seeing some more detailed table structures and so on...

Comment: Thanks dude.its awesome.i got the solution exactly what i needed.thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off working out the points in your code rather than in the SQL

The only way I can think of doing it is with UNIONS which would be horrible

Answer (score 0):

You can use left outer join to your filter condition, group by UserID to not get duplicates, add a value of 1 for hits and use coalesce to set 0 for no hits.

Some sample code that shows what I mean using Area and Country as filter condition.

```
declare @U table (UserID int, Name varchar(50), StaffNo char(3), department char(4))
declare @C table (CountryID int, UserID int)
declare @A table (AreaID int, UserID int)

insert into @U values (1,   'KK',   '111',      'dep1')
insert into @U values (2,   'NN',   '222',      'dep2')
insert into @U values (3,   'DD',   '333',      'dep3')

insert into @C values(1, 1)
insert into @C values(2, 1)
insert into @C values(3, 2)
insert into @C values(3, 3)

insert into @A values(1, 1)
insert into @A values(2, 1)
insert into @A values(3, 2)

select 
  U.UserID,
  U.Name,
  U.StaffNo,
  U.department,
  coalesce(C.Point, 0)+coalesce(A.Point,0) as Points
from @U as U
  left outer join
    (select UserID, 1 as Point
     from @C
     -- where ...?
     group by UserID) as C
    on U.UserID = C.UserID
  left outer join
    (select UserID, 1 as Point
     from @A
     -- where ...?
     group by UserID) as A
    on U.UserID = A.UserID
```